# Can't get Orientation notification on iPhone without UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to develop an iPhone app using xcode13 with iPhone 11 simulator. I used Xcode template to create a basic app. Now I created a new class (not derived from UIViewController) and tried to get orientation notifications, but I am getting nothing. **I tried to add the same code on class that derived from UIViewController and it worked**. why ? why ?

1. Why it is only working from the UIViewController's derived class?
2. Can I make it work from a class that isn't derived from UIViewController ?

here is my code that is not working :

main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Orientation/Orientation.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    NSString * appDelegateClassName;
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Setup code that might create autoreleased objects goes here.
        appDelegateClassName = NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]);
        NSLog(@"Hello world !");
        OrientationService * os = [[OrientationService alloc] init];
        [os onStart];
    }
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, appDelegateClassName);
}
```

Orientation/Orientation.h

```
#ifndef Orientation_h
#define Orientation_h

@interface OrientationService : NSObject {
    NSInteger * orientation_state;
}

- (void) onStart;
- (void) orientationStateDidChange:(NSNotification*) notification;

@end
```

Orientation/Orientation.m

```
#endif /* Orientation_h */

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Orientation.h"
#import <UIKit/Uikit.h>

@implementation OrientationService

-(void) orientationStateDidChange:(NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"got notified");
}

-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"OrientationService alloc");
    return self;
}


-(void)onStart{
    NSLog(@"starting orientation service");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationStateDidChange:) name:(UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification) object:nil];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent so long on this but it just hit me! It's because `os` in `main()` isn't being retained in memory. Instead, either implement the functionality in the App Delegate, or retain an instance of your `OrientationService` object in the App Delegate. For example:

AppDelegate.h

```objectivec
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "Orientation.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) OrientationService *os;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```objectivec
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize os;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    os = [[OrientationService alloc] init];
    [os onStart];
    return YES;
}

@end
```